# income elasticity + regression + household survey data

Tags: regression, survey, quantiles, aggregation

I'll try to be concise and up to the point:

**Problem**: estimate income elasticities for various products from household survey data.

**Given**: I have to big complex household survey datasets that uses two stage stratified sampling. However, I have the design specified (strata variable) for only one, and replicate weights for the other data set.

**The idea**: is to estimate some for of a regression `expenditure_for_product ~ household's income` and then use the coefficients to estimate it's elasticity

**What is unclear**: To estimate simple statistics as mean expenditure for a product or its S.E. one has to properly account for the survey design (especially for variance estimation). But I am not sure how if at all I need to adjust it in my regression case because the literature survey in fact does not provide a clear answer ( whether the weights (and correspondingly the survey design) should be used in my regression case)

**Software**: there is in fact R package `survey` which is capable of incorporating (not sure exactly how, as help files does not specify or I can't locate it) the survey design into regressions but this of course does not mean I actually need to do it in my case.

**A small digression**: For example, say that `log(expenditure_for_product) ~ log(household's income)` captures the relationship nicely. In that case, the regression coefficient would be all that I need. However, as there are many zero purchases reported by households for goods, I cannot model it in logs. I had an idea of aggregating the data into percentiles so that there would be 100 points with `(average income of x percentile, average expenditure for some product of x percentile)`. But how can if at all should adjust this idea for survey design to get correct estimates?

**In essence**: In essence I am looking for a theoretically correct* way to calculate income elasticities given complex household survey data and thus references on this matter or suggestions would be very helpful.

*Note, I cannot incorporate price effects because I do not have price information available, so I realize that it will not be too precise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like you need to run `svyglm` on a complex-sample survey design object that you created with the `svydesign` or `svrepdesign` functions?

if you are talking about the consumer expenditure survey, [the entire setup has already been done for you](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/consumer%20expenditure%20survey%20%28ce%29) all the way to an example regression call in the r language.  just walk through that code and change the `svyglm` call to what you're studying.  even if you're not talking about the consumer expenditure survey, it sounds quite analogous to what you need - so the code might be instructive anyway :)  thanks

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer Anthony. in fact, I have been using your website to get acquainted with how to use `survey` package to analyze complex design surveys, but this questions is not how to do, but whether, do I really need to do it? as I've digressed, if I decide to for example log-log model, then I would somehow transform the data (for example - aggregate into percentiles) to get rid of zero expenditures. but then I of course loose the information about survey design. but the key is - maybe I do not even need this information for my purposes? thanks for your thoughts though!

Comment: @Sarunas i'm not sure, but if you ignore the design, the burden of proof is on you. maybe [run it by bls](http://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/forms/cex?/cex/csxcont.htm)?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. now obviously, the survey design has its influence through the variance estimation. so yeah, even in my case it would be probably a bad idea to ignore it. but I'm still not sure what to do if for example I want to employ log-log model (and to aggregate the data as a result), so hopefully somebody will give some other ideas too. thanks again!

Comment: after some thinking I concluded (without proof) that it would not be a good idea to ignore extra information that is available (survey design), so I accepted your answer. kids - use the `survey` package!